# What type of container is a group in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

Is a regex group a list? Can I do something like this:

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        self._match = (re.search('^CIS\s(\d*\w*)(\w*)\s?[^x]*(.*)$', line, re.I))
        self._numb = self._match.group(0).strip()
        self._name = self._match.group(1).strip()
        self._quarter=self._match.group(2).strip().split('x')
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: What language are you using? (You could put it in the text, to add a tag.)

Comment: yea I tried it. It said group(0) matched the whole line, group(1) matched the course #, group(2) was empty for some reason, and group(3) was the combination of self._name and self._quarter.

Comment: Oh this is python my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group()` is actually a function belonging to the match object.  Calling `_match.group(1)`, for example, will return whatever string happened to match to that particular group.  Calling `groups()` will return a tuple containing all matches.  In the case of `re.findall`, the return value will be a list of tuples, with each tuple containing all groups.

Comment: So group() automatically strips the group?

Comment: `group()` _accesses_ the groups; I don't actually know how the Python regex API implements things internally.  Through `groups()` it exposes all groups as a tuple.

Comment: Thank you for giving such a simple but easy to understand answer!